# jQuery Parents and Data

Tags: php, jquery

So, I have the following php:

```
<div class="top" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
  <div class="middle">
    Click
  </div>
</div>
```

Then for my js:

```
jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.middle', function(e) {
  var my_id= jQuery(this).data("id");   ???
}
```

So at the current setup, when the '`.middle`' class is clicked, then I want to target the ".top" class and save the data-id.

I can use `jQuery(this).parents('.top');` but I am not sure how to combine them together.

My question is, how do I target the parents (`top`) then save the data-id variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.parent()` and chain it for other function invocations.

```
jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.middle', function(e) {
  var my_id= jQuery(this).parent(".top").data("id");
});
```

And in the place of document, try to use any closest static parent of `.middle`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $('.middle').on('click', function() {
        var id = $(this).closest('.top').data('id');
    });
});
```